# Intrinsic numerical methods on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis

I am interested in numerical methods for ordinary differential equations on a Riemannian manifold $M$. The general form of such an equation is $\dot x(t)=V(x(t)), x(0)=x_0 \in M$, where $V$ is a vector field in $M$. I have spent many hours checking the literature and I cannot find any intrinsic general method. I have found many good methods for submanifolds of $\mathbb{R}^n$, e.g. https://www.unige.ch/~hairer/poly-sde-mani.pdf (projected methods, coordinate methods) and many intrinsic methods for specific manifold structures, for instance Lie groups and homogeneous spaces, like https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01328729/document. Recently I found out a reasonable extension of explicit Euler method here https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/cnm.516, i.e. $x_{k+1}=exp_{x_k}(hV(x_k))$. However there is no analysis for the order of the method, i.e. of its local error.

My question is whether there are already established general intrinsic Taylor methods on Riemannian manifolds and more specifically an intrinsic Euler scheme like above, with guaranteed rate for the local error. This is equivalent with the existence of Taylor expansions for curves on manifolds.

Comment: The local error estimate for Euler's method can have a few forms depending on how "local" you choose to make it.  On a small enough scale your Riemann manifold is (for all intents and purposes), just Euclidean space.  So there is a reasonable formulation of a local error estimate that is functionally identical to the Euclidean one.  If you want something more like a Gronwall inequality though you would need to do a bit more work.

Comment: Seems related: https://people.ee.ethz.ch/~bsaverio/papers/Allerton2016.pdf

Comment: One small comment : the problem $\dot x=V(x)$ is independant of the Riemannian structure. An auxiliary Riemannian metric can be used to devise a geometric numerical scheme as in the example you gave, but the Riemannian metric does not play any role in the original problem.

Comment: Ryan: I want to measure the local error intrinsically, e.g. if $X$ is the solution of the ODE and $x_{k+1}=\Phi(x_k)$ a discretization of $X$ with step-size $h$, I care to estimate $dist(X((k+1)h),\Phi(X(kh))$. user35593: This looks like a continuous-time dynamical system without guarantees for the discretized version, it should be named projected gradient flow. Thomas: I assume a fixed Riemannian metrix from the beginning, so practically I would like to have an estimation for any Riemannian metric.